# Maximum no. of records in a REST call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I am trying to insert bulk records in a data extension using the below call

```
POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:{key}/rowset
```

It works well with 10k records but as soon as I increase to 15K, I get

> '500 internal server error'

Is there any per call limit on data volume/no. of records?

Comment: You should reconsider your solution, here. A better design for bulk loads would use Import Activities. They're far more scalable and even if we gave you a magic number (you've already far exceeded that) this is a bad design that'll come back to haunt you as you have to support it.

Comment: you might be hitting a server limit (as opposed to a "protocol" limit. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless)

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably batch them in 5000. 
Can't use Import activity because of some internal infra issues